# Trace of a matrix as a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am attempting to show that a set is a subspace of All $n \times n$ matrices. The set in question is all $n \times n$ where $\text{tr}(A) = 0$.

I am trying to show that $\text{tr}(A)+\text{tr}(B)=\text{tr}(A+B)$
I am getting hung up on this because I see this as $0+0=0$ since we know that were concerned only about matrices where $\text{tr}(A) = 0$.

Is that enough to say that the set is closed under addition?

I also need to show that $\text{tr}(cA) = c\text{tr}(A)$.

For $\text{Tr}(cA)$: multiplying a matrix $A$ by a scalar has no effect on the outcome of the trace, (it's like $2-2$ and $2(2-2)$ which both equal zero).
For $\text{cTr}(A)$: This is just $c0$ which is $0$.

Comment: Please try to avoid summation notation.

Comment: Saying $\operatorname{tr}(A + B) = \operatorname{tr}(A) + \operatorname{tr}(B)$ is pretty similar to saying $0 + 0 = 0$, but not quite. You need to assume $\operatorname{tr}(A) = 0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(B) = 0$, but you're not allowed to assume $\operatorname{tr}(A + B) = 0$, since that's what you're trying to prove!

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason you want to avoid summation notation? The idea that the sum of two traceless matrices is again traceless is a fact which is almost obvious when one thinks of how addition of matrices works. Summation notation is just the cleanest way to $\textit{write down}$ why it is clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:
$$tr(A) = \sum_{i}^{n} a_{ii},$$
So
$$A + B = [a_{ij} + b_{ij}] \qquad\forall i,j.$$

Then
$$tr(A+B) \quad= \quad \sum_{i}^{n}(a_{ii} + b_{ii})\quad=\quad \sum_{i}^{n}a_{ii} + \sum_{i}^{n}b_{ii}\quad = \quad 0+0$$
And let`s go!